# irregular symbols happens when translate docker yaml file

Tags: javascript, yaml

I tried to read a docker file as a template in my program, and replace the detail when new condition happens.but it failed when I use `dump` function.
My code is like:

```
    let yaml  = require('js-yaml');
    let filePath = **/docker-compos-template.yaml';
    let savePath = '**/docker-compose-save.yaml';
    try{
        let doc = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync(filePath),'utf8');
        console.log(doc);
        fs.writeFileSync(savePath, yaml.dump(doc), 'utf8');
    }catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

My part of my template file is ：

```
 environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-santai
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=chembean_default
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.santai.chembean.io-cert.pem
```

and the translated file is:

```
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-santai
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=chembean_default
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - >-
        FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.santai.chembean.io-cert.pem
```

the symbol `>-` is not defined in the template.
and then will be `''` in translate files.
e.g my template file is:

```
environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb-santai:5984

      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.santai.chembean.io
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=chembean
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.santai.chembean.io:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.santai.chembean.io:7051
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.santai.chembean.io:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=1200s
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.santai.chembean.io:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=SantaiMSP
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # bridge network as the peers
      # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=chembean_default
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      #- CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
```

but the translate file is:

```
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - 'CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb-santai:5984'
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.santai.chembean.io
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=chembean
      - 'CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.santai.chembean.io:7051'
      - 'CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.santai.chembean.io:7051'
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - 'CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.santai.chembean.io:7052'
      - 'CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052'
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=1200s
      - 'CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.santai.chembean.io:7051'
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=SantaiMSP
      - 'CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock'
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=chembean_default
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
```

it seems that the symbol `''` appears randomly.
Is there any good idea to help me solve these problems?

Answer (score 1):

Problems might have been arising while parsing and dumping the yaml files. If you could just replace certain strings in yaml files by using [replace-in-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file). Just put <> in the place where you need to replace the texts and put them accordingly.